# Why does saving addresses on a stack give us the only way out for both nesting and "recursing" subroutines?

Tags: computer-architecture

My text (*Computer Organization and Embedded Systems*, 6e, by Hamacher et al.) poses the following:

> Consider the following possibilities for saving the return address of a subroutine:
> (a) In a processor register
> (b) In a memory location associated with the call, so that a different location is used when the subroutine is called from different places
> (c) On a stack

and says that the answer options are:

> (a) Neither nesting nor recursion are supported.
> (b) Nesting is supported, because different Call instructions will save the return address at different memory locations. Recursion is not supported.
> (c) Both nesting and recursion are supported.

I cannot understand the comment regarding (b).

Suppose our solution was (a).

This works for a case where we go "one level deep" but if we nest or recurse then everything except the very last calling function will have the correct returning address clobbered. No problem.

But what of (b)? Is the proposition that every subroutine call would cause the address of the next instruction after the call to be stored somewhere which is a (injective) function of the memory address of the call? If so, where does the problem arise with recursion? I think maybe I'm not getting my arms around even what we're talking about when we say "memory location associated with the call".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a general programming question, not electrical engineering. It probably belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I thought maybe architecture/ISA-level questions were OK but if not I will move it over? @DoxyLover Just to be clear, this is not a question about assembly programming but about architecture decisions around how subroutines ought to return.

Comment: Please add the source of the text you quoted.

Comment: Done, my bad! @internet

Comment: @periblepsis says. Recursion  eats its own tail from the same location and then unwinds. On every loop it needs a new store location.Which is what a stack does.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment @RussellMcMahon I think what I was missing was how specifically the tail eating comes about, and why it can't be avoided. Periblepsis gives a very nice answer below showing an example in which the tail does get eaten and I suppose I'll have to satisfy myself that no one has come up with a way of not having the tail eaten!

Comment: @EE18  Recursion is essentially defined as "tail eating". A routine calls itself repeatedly until some aim is left and then either unwinds, which progressively frees up resources acquired along the way,  or abandons ship  and leaves the system to reacquire the abandoned resources.  In a case where abandoning ship at the end of the process is acceptable then non-stack memory may well be acceptable as you are never going back.

Comment: @DoxyLover Thanks for saying that you were close-voting and why. I consider that it greatly helps understanding when people do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is easy. It says *"(b) In a memory location associated with the call, so that a different location is used when the subroutine **is called from different places**"*.

In the case of recursion, successive calls may come from the ***same place***.

#### added

No one said that the machine architecture for *case (b)* makes a lot of sense or is an easy one to construct and make functional.

But suppose there exists a special 8-bit return address key register called X0 that the return instruction uses and suppose a call instruction performs the following steps:

1. TEMP = HASH8(subroutine address, call instruction address)

   Here, HASH8 is some hardware block that generates an 8-bit hash code from the 16-bit subroutine address and the 16-bit target address of the call instruction.

   It is assumed to be *unlikely* that the same HASH8 generates unwanted collisions (given whatever justification someone comes up with.)

   However, the same call located at the same instruction address making a call to the same subroutine ***will*** produce the same HASH8.
2. R[TEMP]= 16-bit return address from call

   R[] is a 16-bit wide data memory with an 8-bit address.
3. X[TEMP]= X0

   X[] is an 8-bit wide data memory with an 8-bit address.
4. X0 = TEMP
5. PC = 16-bit address of called subroutine

Suppose the return instruction performs:

1. TEMP = X0
2. X0 = X[TEMP]
3. PC = R[TEMP]

Don't ask me why anyone would do it this way. I just made it up. But it does match *case (b)* in your example.

Hopefully, now you can see the problem with recursion in a situation posed by *case (b)*.

By the way, the HP21xx series of CPUs would literally ***blow away*** the first address of any called subroutine with the return address of the caller. (No stacks here!) A subroutine would look something like this:

```
FDATE   NOP             This location gets overwritten with return address of caller.
        LDA FILE#       Subroutine always starts here.
        SSA,RSS
        .
        .
        .
        JMP FDATE,I     Return from call.
```

All calls blow away the first address with the return address and then always start the subroutine at addr+1.

Now, that certainly doesn't support recursion!

Comment: Agreed, and if they do come from the same place then won't things work out fine? Suppose `main()` calls some function `recurse()` which in turn calls `recurse()` from line \$n\$ of the subroutine, and that in turn calls `recurse()` from line \$n\$ of the subroutine, and that is it for the recursion. So the deepest `recurse()` returns and it knows (I guess? I don't know how one would arrange this?) where to look for the memory address which is holding the address of line \$n+1\$ of recurse. Now the second deepest `recurse()` also returns and it uses the aforementioned, same address. So yes,...

Comment: ...even though it got clobbered, it got clobbered with the same value, didn't it?

Comment: There also seems to me to be a problem with what it even means to have a "memory location associated with the call". How would a returning subroutine know in general where to look? With our usual solution with a link register there is no problem -- everyone looks in the same place, namely the link register. I'm guessing the answer to this latter question will explain why recursion from the same place won't work. I have a vague sense that it's the crux of my misunderstanding.

Comment: @EE18 Don't you see why the same location is a problem???

Comment: I do not, no, at least to the extent that the returning function knows what called it (but again not sure how it would actually know that). If you're able to supply an example showing the problem when you get the chance I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @EE18 I guess I'm shocked. ... What happens when there are 5 recursive calls?

Comment: I am not sure, hence my question :) I gave an explanation I thought was correct in the case of 3 calls above but obviously that's not right

Comment: @ee18 The first thing you need to do is to ***design a machine*** where the call instruction behaves as described in case (b). I can suggest an idea. But I don't know if you will follow it. Assume an associative memory where the key is the address of the call instruction and the value stored adjacent to the key is the return address. Suppose also that the call instruction either adds or updates this associative memory when making a call. Suppose also that the call instruction also automatically places the key into a special register upon making the call so the caller can use the key to return.

Comment: @EE18 Do you follow, so far? (There's more to grasp, but no point going further if I've already lost you.) I'd actually prefer it that you come up with your own approach than use mine. But I'm trying to push you into thinking closely about what *case (b)* implies.

Comment: I do follow somewhat, but I have two questions. (1) What is the point of the key? Why not just put the value in said register (but then that is equivalent to (a))? (2) Other than (1), I follow everything. Under the given design, I am still not sure I see the issue with the deep recursion. If we have the same caller (same instruction in the memory) calling 5 times, what goes wrong? I think this may be related to my misunderstanding in (1).

Comment: @EE18 I don't think you are allowed to ask ***why***. In fact, I don't think there is a good reason readily available. I could make up such a need, but it would be entirely made up out of whole cloth. I can, though, point you to a case that actually exists that does the opposite: *There is only one memory location reserved for the return address of each subroutine.* This would be the Hewlett-Packard 21xx CPU.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for taking the time to write that very detailed explanation, I really appreciate it. I think it gets me pretty much all the way to understanding but I want to confirm with you if that's OK. At a high level, if I'm understanding correctly, we are using this register X0 to hold the HASH8 output of the most recent call. Thus, when we call some subroutine again, we must *save* the current contents of X0 somewhere (imagining we are two or more subroutine calls deep) and, according to the specifications of (b) from the OP, that save occurs somewhere depending on...

Comment: ...TEMP, i.e. the HASH8 output of the most recent call. Thus, when we go two levels deep on the *same* function call from the *same* place we end up blowing up whatever was saved at X[TEMP]. I guess my last and final question for you before I accept is the following: the crux of the issue with this method seems to be the need for a centralized register X0 which is used to return from calls (analogous to link register). Why I was originally confused was that I was wondering about some sort of "decentralized" way to return from functions, but I definitely agree that if the authors meant...

Comment: ...something like what you gave by their (b) then certainly it would not allow for recursion. Thanks again!

Comment: @ee18 TEMP is an internal (not exposed to the programmer) register. It's used only for a short time during the execution of an instruction. You won't see it as a programmer. The memories R and X are also NOT EXPOSED to the programmer, who cannot see any of their contents. And yes X0 is a register that the subroutine should not mess with (at least, normal subroutines should not) but is the sole link it has to properly return from the call. Of course, I'm just making this stuff up as I go and I'd never implement this idea for any reason I can imagine.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you again! I've gone ahead and accepted although I fear this question will get deleted given that it's already been closed. I usually like to have them as a record of somewhere to refer to from my texts, but alas...